# Part of file name as a variable

Tags: variables, stata, stata-macros

I have a list of files with similar names, for example:

- 2002_file
- 2003_file
- 2004_file

I am going to run a simple script:

```
foreach year in 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 {  
use "$input\`year'_file.dta ", clear
keep v1 v2 v3
tab v1, gen (v1_dummy)
gen year = 'x'
save "$output\`year'_newfile.dta ", replace
}
```

However, I would like for one of the files to be created the respective year variable.

How can I add a variable year = `'year'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not define the local macro `x` anywhere.

The following should work:

```
foreach year in 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 {
    use "$input\`year'_file.dta ", clear
    keep v1 v2 v3
    tab v1, gen (v1_dummy)
    gen year = `year'
    save "$output\`year'_newfile.dta ", replace
}
```

For a specific year only:

```
foreach year in 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 {
    use "$input\`year'_file.dta ", clear
    keep v1 v2 v3
    tab v1, gen (v1_dummy)
    if `year' == 2005 gen year = `year'
    save "$output\`year'_newfile.dta ", replace
}
```

Comment: You're right, I corrected the question!

Every case makes no difference, this mistake I made now writing the question and adapting the example.

Comment: @JoyceMaia Do you want the variable to be added in the new file for a specific year only?

Comment: I need to make this part of the filename that matches the year a variable (gen year = `x '), but I do not know how.

Comment: The error was the lack of quotes "` x '" or "` year'".

Comment: @JoyceMaia You do not need quotes. If you use quotes you will create a string `year` variable instead of a numeric one.

Comment: If I do not put it as a string, for some reason an error occurs when saving the new file names. Saves as `x' instead of years.

Comment: @JoyceMaia Sorry but i cannot reproduce your problem. The altered code snipped that i provided above works as expected on my computer.